# Modernize legacy OctoberCMS project to Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, octobercms, legacy

I have an old (kinda legacy) OctoberCMS project which is using Laravel 5.5 version (it's already used by a couple of customers, and they are happy with it).
I want to migrate it to pure Laravel 8 app step by step.

**After I did some research, I end up with 2 options:**

1. Start it from scratch, and migrate some reusable components from OctoberCMS (which will take much time and risk).
2. Create a new Laravel app and migrate the legacy features/modules one by one, and deploy them live, till all features are migrated.

So, did anyone face this challenge before? so he can provide me with some advice/recommendations?

Here are some resources I went through:

https://tighten.co/blog/converting-a-legacy-app-to-laravel/

https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/why-your-team-should-not-upgrade-old-laravel-applications/

Comment: 2nd option would be best as someday you need to do that, to remove all dependencies .. so sooner is better than later ... you will save lot of efforts in long run